# Why the javascript function is not getting called if I add an extra parameter

Tags: php, javascript, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a really weird situation, I am calling my javascript function like this...

```
window.top.window.stopUpload(<? echo $result; ?>,<? echo $file_name; ?>);
```

Javascript function looks like this,

```
function stopUpload(success,filePath){
          var result = '';
          if (success == 1){
             result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!<\/span><br/><br/>';
          }
          else {
             result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!<\/span><br/><br/>';
          }
          document.getElementById('f1_upload_process').style.visibility = 'hidden';
          document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').innerHTML = result + '<input name="image_file" type="file" class="browse" /><input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Upload"  class="browse"/>';
          document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').style.visibility = 'visible';     
           
          return true;   
    }
```

Above code does't execute `stopUpload` function.

---

However If I do like this,

```
window.top.window.stopUpload(<? echo $result; ?>);
```

and javascript like this,

```
function stopUpload(success){
          var result = '';
          if (success == 1){
             result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!<\/span><br/><br/>';
          }
          else {
             result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!<\/span><br/><br/>';
          }
          document.getElementById('f1_upload_process').style.visibility = 'hidden';
          document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').innerHTML = result + '<input name="image_file" type="file" class="browse" /><input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Upload"  class="browse"/>';
          document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').style.visibility = 'visible';     
           
          return true;   
    }
```

With one one param, it works!

## Question

Why it works with one param and not with 2? I have tried sending normal string like `'hello'` instead of `$file_name` but still it does't call.

Comment: have you echo'd $file_name outside of the function to ensure there is a value?

Comment: Load the page in your browser and check the source. Odds are that `$result` or `$file_name` is `null`, in which case it would lead to bad syntax (i.e. `window.top.window.stopUpload(,'hello'`)

Comment: Make sure that you escape your arguments with quotes, i.e. `window.top.window.stopUpload('<? echo $result; ?>','<? echo $file_name; ?>');`

Comment: Thnks to all! problems solved! Very silly mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call your function like this:

```
window.top.window.stopUpload(<? echo $result; ?>,'<? echo $file_name; ?>');
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`window.top.window.stopUpload('<? echo $result; ?>','<? echo $file_name; ?>');`

Remember, $result should not be any numerical value. User $result = '1' instead.

And change success == '1') in your if statement.

Hope it helps.